# Deprecated JQuery Methods in YII app (yii 1.1.4)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I want to change the jquery in my yii apps, using jquery 1.9 instead of using the jquery from yii.

But I found that some methods are depreacted such as $.browser() and $.live() in jquery-ba-bbq.js and main.js

My question:
1. how to remove both js since they are autoload by the yii apps. Which config file I should use.
2. should I use modernzr lib instead ?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Re your first question, use the `clientScript` `scriptMap` option in your config file:

```
...
'clientScript' => array(
    'scriptMap' => array(
        'jquery.min.js' => 'your URL or Google CDN link',
    ),
), 
...
```

You can do the same for using your upgraded libs for jQuery compatibility. If you do fix the compatibility bugs, please send in some pull requests with your updates, so that the main jQuery library can be updated down the road too :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    'clientScript'=>array(

        'packages'=>array(
            'jquery'=>array(
                   'baseUrl'=> 'siteasset/jquery' ,
                   'js'=>array('jquery-1.10.2.min.js','jquery.browser.js'),

                   // you can also add css files  
                   'css'=>array('css file path') 
            ) 
        ),
    ),
```

put this in your main.php file under config folder... in main.php under components.... and register your package in controller.php under components folder.. where your controller .php should be like this

```
<?php


 class Controller extends CController
 {
/**
 * @var string the default layout for the controller view. Defaults to '//layouts/column1',
 * meaning using a single column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column1.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/content';
/**
 * @var array context menu items. This property will be assigned to {@link CMenu::items}.
 */
public $menu=array();
/**
 * @var array the breadcrumbs of the current page. The value of this property will
 * be assigned to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}. Please refer to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}
 * for more details on how to specify this property.
 */
public $breadcrumbs=array();


    public function beforeAction($action) {

                      $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
                      $url = Yii::app()->baseUrl;

                     if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
                     {

                     }
                     else
                     {  

                      $cs->registerPackage('jquery');

                                             // here you can also register your another css
                                             // and js file .. this code will be 
                                             //  executed every time before an action
                                             //  is called via ajax or in normal way..

                                             //another thing here you can also controll 
                                             //in which type of request which scipts
                                             // shiould be generated again.. 
                                             //here you can see i am not sending 
                                             //any js /css files if there is ajax request

                    }

                      return parent::beforeAction($action);

     }
```

}

via this you can change you js/css files which came from your default Yii framework....

**also i want to include that as for jquery1.7 and greater ... there is no jquery.browser.js is not included so you have to download it seperately and attach it as independantly.   you can get it here [jquery.browser.js](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/)**